# Can't get rails working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to get rails working.  I've been following the tutorial [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)
and it doesn't seem to want to work due to mysql problems or something..  I am currently on windows and I also have wamp installed.  I installed ruby using railsinstaller from railsinstaller.org. Anyway in the browser I'm getting this error:

```
Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/jdbcmysql_adapter)
```

The trouble is that I continue to install this and then I don't get an error but It just says that active record failed to connect and as soon as I shutdown the server it throws the jdbcmysql error again.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: @andrew honestly I really don't know. What command would I type to find out?  I just started ruby about 2 hours ago.

Comment: What does `ruby --version` output?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 <2011-02-18 patchlevel 334> [i386-mingw32]

Comment: never thought netbeans IDE could overwrite `database.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using JRuby, there's no reason to be using the JDBC MySQL adapter like you are.

In your `config/database.yml` file in your Rails application's root directory, find where it says `adapter:` and change whatever that line to:

```
adapter: mysql2
```

For more details on configuration see the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-mysql-database). You'll then have to install the `mysql2` gem.

Comment: this still didn't work, but after some more digging around I think I may have found the problem.  Netbeans seems to be forcing me to use jruby rather than the default interpreter.  Should I just let it?  Otherwise I don't know where the default interpreter is..

Comment: Unless you have a reason to use JRuby, you should probably use MRI instead. It's probably installed in `c:\Ruby`.